Effect Size Calculation from 2-way ANOVA results: Meta-analysis
I am currently extracting data for a meta-analysis on continuous outcomes.
I am extracting means and standard deviations for two separate groups (patients and controls) and will later calculate standardised mean difference as the effect size (Cohen's d).
I am finding that some papers only report ANOVA results (F statistic, p-value). I understand how to calculate standard error from p-values, but I do not know how to obtain the effect size Cohen's d. Specifically, I need this effect size for the interaction term of

a 2 (patients vs controls) x 2 (task conditions) ANOVA, and

a 2 (patients vs controls) x 4 (task conditions) ANOVA.


